# Get unbiased derivative from GAM

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, gradient

I have time-dependent data and I'm interested in the gradient at time zero. From theory I expect the gradient of the true relationship to be highest at time zero.

I would like to estimate the derivative at time zero using a GAM. However, the estimates are biased (too low). How can I reduce or preferably eliminate that bias?

```
#HM function
HM <- function(t, f0, phi, kappa) phi + f0 * exp(-kappa * t)/(-kappa)

t <- 0:180
phi <- 530
kappa <- 0.025
f0 <- 5
Ctrue <- HM(t, f0, phi, kappa)

sdC <- 5

library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

set.seed(1)
res <- replicate(100, {
  
  C <- Ctrue + rnorm(length(t), sd = sdC)
  
  DF <- data.frame(C, t)
  
  
  fit <- gam(C ~ s(t, bs = "bs", k = 5), data = DF)
  #gam.check(fit)
  
  #ggplot(DF, aes(t, C)) +
  #  geom_point() +
  #  stat_function(fun = \(t) predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(t)))
  
  derivatives(fit, data = data.frame(t = 0))
  
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

[image: example fit]

```
res <- do.call(rbind, res)

summary(res$derivative)
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#4.266   4.432   4.508   4.517   4.589   4.773

#True value is 5
```

Comment: Not good enough for an answer: When you use shape-constrained GAM (package scam), you can force the smooth to be monotonously positive. The derivative function does not work (but there is a stand-in), and while it does not fully remove the bias in my simulation, but at least the replicates now overlap with 5. Here the essential changes in code: `library(scam)`; `fit <- scam(C ~ s(t, bs="mpi", k = 5), data = DF)` and `derivative.scam(fit)$d[1,]`.

Comment: @Carsten Thanks. If I also enforce concave smoothers, there is a small further improvement. But there is still bias. (Also, something isn't right with the `derivative.scam` function. It doesn't apear to give correct derivatives with `bs = "micv"`. I needed to do it manually: `diff(predict(fits[[i]], newdata = data.frame(t = c(0, 1e-7)))) / 1e-7`)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you may need to increase the potential complexity of the basis (i.e. increase `k`) and perhaps even extend the range of the penalty beyond zero to get more accurate and correct estimates of the slope at `t = 0`. I used your same data-generating process and, with these modifications, got a better answer (note that I'm using {`marginaleffects`} for these calculations, but I'm certain you could do this just as well with {`gratia`}:

```r
library(mgcv)
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

#HM function
HM <- function(t, f0, phi, kappa) phi + f0 * exp(-kappa * t)/(-kappa)

set.seed(1)
t <- 0:180
phi <- 530
kappa <- 0.025
f0 <- 5
Ctrue <- HM(t, f0, phi, kappa)
sdC <- 5
C <- Ctrue + rnorm(length(t), sd = sdC)
DF <- data.frame(C, t)

# The model
fit <- gam(C ~ 
             # Use larger 'k' for more flexibility, 
             # particularly near the endpoints
             s(t, bs = "bs", k = 10),
           
           # Extend penalty beyond zero for more effective 
           # estimates of derivatives at the bound
           knots = list(t = c(-5, 0, 180, 185)),
           data = DF)
#> Warning in smooth.construct.bs.smooth.spec(object, dk$data, dk$knots): there is
#> *no* information about some basis coefficients

# The estimated function, on the response scale
plot_predictions(fit, condition = 't',
                 points = 0.5)
```

[image]

```r
# Estimated slopes (using a finer grid of points for a smoother image)
plot_slopes(fit, 
            newdata = datagrid(t = seq(0, 180, by = 0.2)),
            variables = 't', by = 't')
```

[image]

```r
# Estimated slope at t = 0, with appropriate uncertainty envelope
slopes(fit, 
       newdata = datagrid(t = seq(0, 180, by = 0.2)),
       variables = 't', by = 't')[1,]
#> 
#>  Term    Contrast t Estimate Std. Error  z Pr(>|z|)     S 2.5 % 97.5 %
#>     t mean(dY/dX) 0     4.72      0.336 14   <0.001 146.0  4.06   5.38
#> 
#> Columns: rowid, term, contrast, t, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted 
#> Type:  response

# Does the estimate at t = 0 differ 'significantly' from 5?
hypotheses(slopes(fit, 
                  newdata = datagrid(t = seq(0, 180, by = 0.2)),
                  variables = 't', by = 't'),
           hypothesis = 5)[1,]
#> 
#>  Term    Contrast t Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
#>     t mean(dY/dX) 0     4.72      0.336 -0.841      0.4 1.3  4.06   5.38
#> 
#> Columns: rowid, term, contrast, t, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted 
#> Type:  response
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-25 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can read more about how the penalty can be extended in this way using b-splines in [Gavin Simpson's helpful post on spline extrapolation](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2020/06/03/extrapolating-with-gams/)